# Create multiple random pairwise combination of words

Tags: shell-script, awk, perl

File 1 contains the list of words that needed to be randomly paired

```
Tiger
Cat 
Fish
Frog
Dog
Mouse
Elephant
Monkey
```

File 2 contains the pairs that should not be used (in any solution) during random pairing.

```
Elephant-Dog
Cat-Fish
Monkey-Frog
```

Dog-Elephant, Fish-Cat, Frog-Monkey should also be deleted as their pair appeared in File2 (irrespective to direction)
I need total of 6 solutions and in every solution, there should be maximum of 5 pairs.
Tiger-Cat and Cat-Tiger should be treated as same and if they appear together in any solution one should be deleted.
The same pair such as Frog-Dog can appear in many solutions.

The output looks like (here only one solution is given)

```
Tiger-Cat
Cat-Dog
Monkey-Cat
Frog-Dog
Elephant-Cat
```

Comment: Is `Cat-Cat` permitted?

Comment: Nice task. What is your question? Did you encounter any problems on solving the task or what?

Comment: no, such pairs are not permitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use List::Util qw{ shuffle };

open my $fh_list, '<', shift or die $!;
chomp( my @words = sort <$fh_list> );

open my $fh_ban, '<', shift or die $!;
my %ban;
while (<$fh_ban>) {
    chomp;
    my ($ban1, $ban2) = sort split /-/;
    undef $ban{"$ban1-$ban2"};
}

my @all;
for my $i1 (0 .. $#words) {
    for my $i2 ($i1 + 1 .. $#words) {
        my $pair = [ $i1, $i2 ];
        push @all, $pair unless exists $ban{"$words[$i1]-$words[$i2]"};
    }
}

my @solutions;
my %used;
while (@solutions < 6) {
    my $solution = join ' ', sort +(shuffle(0 .. $#all))[0 .. 4];
    redo if exists $used{$solution};

    undef $used{$solution};
    push @solutions, [
        map join('-', @words[
            @{ $all[$_] }[int rand 2 ? (0, 1) : (1, 0)]
        ]), split ' ', $solution
    ];
}

say join "\n", @$_, '---' for @solutions;
```

It first reads the words into an array and the banned pairs into a hash. It then generates all the possible combinations where the first element sorts before the second one. It then shuffles the all possible pairs and selects the first five until it has 6 different solutions. The "@all" array contains just the indices of the elements, and they are randomly shuffled when outputting the corresponding elements, so you can get both "Cat-Dog" and "Dog-Cat".

Example output:

```
Elephant-Cat
Monkey-Cat
Fish-Elephant
Monkey-Fish
Frog-Tiger
---
Tiger-Cat
Tiger-Fish
Fish-Elephant
Dog-Monkey
Cat-Frog
---
Tiger-Fish
Cat-Elephant
Elephant-Frog
Mouse-Elephant
Frog-Cat
---
Tiger-Fish
Mouse-Fish
Monkey-Fish
Frog-Tiger
Cat-Dog
---
Dog-Frog
Elephant-Frog
Dog-Tiger
Tiger-Mouse
Tiger-Monkey
---
Tiger-Cat
Elephant-Frog
Tiger-Mouse
Cat-Frog
Cat-Dog
---
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` solution:

```bsh
for i in {1..6}; do

    printf '==== solution %d ====\n' "$i"

    # initialize solution
    solution=()

    while [ ${#solution[@]} -lt 5 ]; do
        # select two random lines from file1
        w1=$(shuf -n 1 file1)
        w2=$(shuf -n 1 file1)

        # skip if word1 is the same as word2
        [ "$w1" == "$w2" ] && continue

        # skip if pair exists in same solution or is not allowed from file2
        cat <(printf '%s\n' "${solution[@]}") file2 | grep -qx "$w1-$w2" && continue
        cat <(printf '%s\n' "${solution[@]}") file2 | grep -qx "$w2-$w1" && continue

        # output
        solution+=("${w1}-${w2}")
    done
    printf '%s\n' "${solution[@]}"
done
```

Output:

```
==== solution 1 ====
Fish-Monkey
Elephant-Mouse
Dog-Tiger
Mouse-Fish
Dog-Cat
==== solution 2 ====
Cat-Frog
Elephant-Monkey
Cat-Mouse
Tiger-Elephant
Fish-Tiger
==== solution 3 ====
Cat-Frog
Tiger-Monkey
Frog-Elephant
Dog-Fish
Elephant-Cat
==== solution 4 ====
Cat-Dog
Mouse-Elephant
Monkey-Elephant
Cat-Monkey
Tiger-Cat
==== solution 5 ====
Tiger-Monkey
Tiger-Cat
Mouse-Monkey
Mouse-Fish
Monkey-Cat
==== solution 6 ====
Monkey-Mouse
Dog-Monkey
Monkey-Fish
Tiger-Elephant
Cat-Tiger
```